# Interactive Blender Enviroment

Tags: game-engine, blend4web

I am about to develop an application with blender and the openpose library. I want to read the pose of the person using the application and replicate it in it's avatar inside the enviroment.

I saw blend4web and was going to attack this problem this way. I am not sure this is the only and easisest way to tackle it... does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used the BGE and a python script that interacts as a client. It communicates via socket with the server as it updates it current position in the enviroment.